# Posh-SSH PowerShell How to get filename and status, and add line to log file

Tags: powershell, logging, status, get-childitem, posh-ssh

Im trying copy file to SFTP server i use posh shh and if it was successfully moved then I get the filename and add new line in Log file, otherwise i add line that file wasnt move or file not in source dir.
I understand how to copy and add line into the log file but i cant bring the  right logic in to this script.

Pls see my code below:

```
# SFTP Upload of Inventory From CSV files to WPEngine SFTP. Requires installation of Posh-SSH 
# Install-Module -Name Posh-SSH (https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH)
 
# Set the credentials
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'almighty1992' -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('sftpuser', $Password)
 
# Set local file path and SFTP path
$FilePath1 = "D:\TEST.txt"

$SftpPath = '/shared/'
 
# Set the Hostname of the SFTP server
$SftpServer = '192.168.1.215'
 
# Load the Posh-SSH module
#Import-Module Posh-SSH
 
# Establish the SFTP connection
$ThisSession = New-SFTPSession -ComputerName $SftpServer -Credential $Credential -AcceptKey -Port 22
 
# Upload the files to the SFTP path
Set-SFTPFile -SessionId ($ThisSession).SessionId -Localfile $FilePath1 -RemotePath $SftpPath -Overwrite

 
#Disconnect all SFTP Sessions
Get-SFTPSession | % { Remove-SFTPSession -SessionId ($_.SessionId) }

Add-Content D:\LOG.TXT "Test"
```

**Code which i dont know how to add.
If im right understand i need to check that file exist in source directory.**

> #check source file exist   Test-Path -Path D:\TEST.txt -PathType Leaf
>
> ## lists sftp directory files after file was copied   $FilePath = Get-SFTPChildItem -sessionID $SFTPSession.SessionID -path $SftpPath
>
> #For each file  ForEach ($LocalFile in $FilePath) {
>
> ```
> if($LocalFile.name -eq "." -Or $LocalFile.name -eq ".." )
> {
>       Write-Host "Files Ignored!"
> }
> else
> {
>     Write-Host $LocalFile
>     Get-SFTPFile -SessionId $SFTPSession.SessionID -LocalPath $LocalPath -RemoteFile $localfile.fullname
> ```
>
> Force
> }
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

Get the list of files from the SFTP session

```
$Files = (Get-SFTPChildItem -SessionId $Session.SessionId -Path "$sftpRemotePath") | Select-object Name,FullName,Length | Sort-Object FullName
```

**Filter the /. and /..**

```
$msgFiles = $Files | where-object {$_.FullName -ne "/." -and $_.FullName -ne "/.."}
```

**Add the files to the log separated by new line after each file**

```
$filelist = $msgFiles | Foreach-Object " ${($_.Name)`n"}
```

**Finally add the filelist to the log file**

```
Add-Content -value $filelist -Path $logfile
```

Note: change the variables where necessary.